# subset matrix based on cell values

Tags: r, matrix, subset

This should be simple, but I cannot figure it out:

I have a square matrix with integer values in each cell (result of an all vs all distance calculation).  I would like to subset the matrix based on the cell values, e.g. cell == 8, or cell <= 6 , etc.

```
foo[1:5, 1:5]
                CASSLLAGAPEQFF CASSQVGLATGTQYF CASSSGTQYTQYF CASRITSGGKTQYF CATSDSRGKTQYF
CASSLLAGAPEQFF               0             999           999              8           999
CASSQVGLATGTQYF            999               0           999            999           999
CASSSGTQYTQYF              999             999             0            999             6
CASRITSGGKTQYF               8             999           999              0           999
CATSDSRGKTQYF              999             999             6            999             0
```

dput:

structure(c(0, 999, 999, 8, 999, 999, 0, 999, 999, 999, 999, 
999, 0, 999, 6, 8, 999, 999, 0, 999, 999, 999, 6, 999, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("CASSLLAGAPEQFF", "CASSQVGLATGTQYF", 
"CASSSGTQYTQYF", "CASRITSGGKTQYF", "CATSDSRGKTQYF"), c("CASSLLAGAPEQFF", 
"CASSQVGLATGTQYF", "CASSSGTQYTQYF", "CASRITSGGKTQYF", "CATSDSRGKTQYF"
)))

Expected result of cell == 8 would be a 2x2 matrix of

```
               CASSLLAGAPEQFF  CASRITSGGKTQYF
CASSLLAGAPEQFF 0                8
CASRITSGGKTQYF 8                0
```

The row and column names don't matter to the subsetting (but I want to keep the names).  What is the most straightforward way to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small example of what you have. When you say "all vs all distance calculation" do you mean you've used `dist` and now have an object of class dist?

Comment: I've used stringdistmatrix() to create this object.

Comment: Please add `dput(foo[1:5, 1:5])` to the question and also show the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `==8` with any other filtering criterion.

```
foo[rowSums(foo==8)>0,colSums(foo==8)>0]
#               CASSLLAGAPEQFF CASRITSGGKTQYF
#CASSLLAGAPEQFF              0              8
#CASRITSGGKTQYF              8              0
```

`rowSums(foo==8)>0` finds any row where at least one element of `foo==8` is `TRUE`.
`colSums(foo==8)>0` does the same for each column.

Comment: Thank you, that will work for what I need to do.  I forget about using logicals inside rowSums()